# 'Is not' operator with custom 'throw exception' helper method makes variable unnasigned

Tags: c#, exception, pattern-matching, throw

Let's say we have a code like this:

```
if (obj is not IFoo foo)
{
    throw new ArgumentException("Can't do that!");         
}
foo.Foo();
```

Works as expected: `foo` is not assigned in the `if` context, but is assigned after.

But, if I want to make a throw helper for inlining and readability purposes - it stops working.

```
if (obj is not IFoo foo)
{
    ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException("Can't do that!");         
}
foo.Foo(); // CS0165
```

I can see why, the compiler doesn't know that `ThrowHelper` methods throw exceptions, so it thinks we can get further to foo, which the `is not` pattern does not allow.

Question: is there any way out of this situation? I understand, that i can invert the `if`, but i'm curious: can i "mark" `ThrowHelper` methods so the compiler knows that it always throws an exception?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.codeanalysis.doesnotreturnattribute?view=net-8.0

Comment: Get rid of ThrowHelper and throw exceptions the paradigmatic way

Comment: What exactly is the "paradigmatic way"? In .NET 8, Microsoft is pushing the use of throw helpers for `ArgumentNullException`, `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`, `ObjectDisposedException`, and even `ArgumentException` for strings that are empty or whitespace.

Comment: @madreflection as in `throw new X()` where X is your exception. If .NET 8 is rolling out new throw helpers then that's nice, use them if you want. I also liked the proposal for  the `!!` operator on method parameters, but that never made it into 6 or 7 because of other syntactic or compiler considerations. All in all, use of whatever .NET has out of the box will be sufficient.

Comment: This question tells us nothing about what `ThrowHelper` is actually doing so diagnosing the true problem is hard here....hence, just get rid of it, because, what else can someone say?

Comment: Apparently, `[DoesNotReturn]` doesn't do what I was expecting. If you add it to `ThrowArgumentException`, the compiler doesn't seem to accept that it won't return. I'm a bit perplexed by this. Anyway,. if you just want to standardize construction, return the exception and then throw it at the call site.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2555

Comment: One option is `throw ThrowHelper.CreateException()` to abstract out everything except the `throw`

Comment: @Narish ThrowHelper methods is nothing more than `throw new ArgumentException(message, innerException);` in this case.
And none of the attributes worked. I'm very curious.

Answer (score -1):

foo.Foo() is the problem ... "foo" is scoped (and "not" scoped) to the "if block" (via "is" and "not"); foo.Foo() is "outside" of that scope.

Comment: Wouldn't that make the first block not work, though?  Allegedly it does...

Comment: @cHao If you're refering to the "if block", it "works" because it doesn't actually reference "foo" (which would fail).

Comment: The code in the first example _does_ reference `foo`.  Same as the other one does.  But allegedly only one of them triggers an error.

Comment: @cHao We differ in our definition of "references" ... the "if block" in effect creates a "scoped" null "foo".

Comment: And the code *right after it*, in *both* examples, actually uses that `foo`. If one works and the other doesn't, you can't really blame it on `foo.Foo()`, as it seem to work in one case and not the other.

Comment: @cHao All you're doing is speculating ("if"). I actually "tested" it (NET 7.0); and stand by my comments. If one goes simply by "intellisense" in VS, it goes "schizo" at this  point. ("Using" and "compiling" and "executing" are not the same thing).  Until you "test it", we're done. You're not even the OP and simply going by hearsay.

Comment: I literally create a project to test it.  Works fine (as in, intellisenses properly, compiles, and runs exactly as it should), *if* you throw the exception in the `if` block.  `foo` is definitely assigned after the `if` block.  Call a "throw an exception" function instead, and the variable is no longer definitely assigned.  You're definitively wrong about the reason.  If you believe otherwise, might want to post the tests that make it make sense.

Comment: First example works completely fine, .Net 8.0.2, i use the `is not` pattern almost everywhere in my project. `Is` with `not` somehow inverting variables scoping, so variables outside of `if` context are scoped(but only when we `return` or `throw` in the `if` сontext).